# How to catch the Integer overflow error in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, validation, integer-overflow

I am using Spring MVC 3.0.5. Spring happily ignores an Integer overflow for a field that is mapped to an Integer. How can I report a proper error on that ?

Comment: Usually, you don't want it to go negative, so you can test for that. In addition, it is bad when you add two numbers and you get a number smaller than the larger (same for multiplication of ints other than zero).

Comment: I think the answer below is probably what you are looking for, but it could have been helpful if you had provided some actual code to demonstrate where the problem was occuring.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a Spring problem, it is a general Java Problem. Java has no overflow problem like C, but it wraps around the integer.

```
@Test
public void demoIntegerWrapp(){
  int value = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  value += 1;
  assertEquals(Integer.MIN_VALUE, value);
}
```

So the best think you can do is using long for calculation and check if the result is in the range of interger, else throw an exception.

```
public int overflowSaveAdd(int summand1, int summand2) {
  long sum = ((long) summand1) + ((long) summand2);
  if (sum < Integer.MIN_VALUE ) || (sum > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
     throw new RuntimeException(sum + " is too big for integer");
  } else {
     return (int) sum;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are Java libraries that provide safe arithmetic operations, which check integer overflow/underflow. For example, Guava's [IntMath.checkedAdd(int a, int b)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html#checkedAdd%28int,%20int%29) returns the sum of `a` and `b`, provided it does not overflow, and throws `ArithmeticException` if `a + b` overflows in signed `int` arithmetic.